# Assign puppet Hash to hieradata yaml

Tags: json, yaml, puppet, hiera

I want to assign a hash variable from puppet to a hiera data structure but i only get a string.

Here is a example to illustrate, what I want. Finaly I don't want to access a fact.

```
1 ---
2  filesystems:
3    - partitions: "%{::partitions}"
```

And here is my debug code:

```
1   $filesystemsarray = lookup('filesystems',Array,'deep',[])
2   $filesystems = $filesystemsarray.map | $fs | {
3     notice("fs: ${fs['partitions']}")
4   }
5 
6   notice("sda1: ${filesystemsarray[0]['partitions']['/dev/sda1']}")
```

The `map` leads to the following output:

```
Notice: Scope(Class[Profile::App::Kms]): fs: {"/dev/mapper/localhost--vg-root"=>{"filesystem"=>"ext4", "mount"=>"/", "size"=>"19.02 GiB", "size_bytes"=>20422066176, "uuid"=>"02e2ba2c-2ee4-411d-ac63-fc963c8026b4"}, "/dev/mapper/localhost--vg-swap_1"=>{"filesystem"=>"swap", "size"=>"512.00 MiB", "size_bytes"=>536870912, "uuid"=>"95ba4b2a-7434-48fd-9331-66443c752a9e"}, "/dev/sda1"=>{"filesystem"=>"ext2", "mount"=>"/boot", "partuuid"=>"de90a5ed-01", "size"=>"487.00 MiB", "size_bytes"=>510656512, "uuid"=>"398f2ab6-a7e8-4983-bd81-db03984fbd0e"}, "/dev/sda2"=>{"size"=>"1.00 KiB", "size_bytes"=>1024}, "/dev/sda5"=>{"filesystem"=>"LVM2_member", "partuuid"=>"de90a5ed-05", "size"=>"19.52 GiB", "size_bytes"=>20961034240, "uuid"=>"wLKRQm-9bdn-mHA8-M8bE-NL76-Gmas-L7Gp0J"}}
```

Seem to be a Hash as expected but the `notice` in Line 6 leads to:

```
Error: Evaluation Error: A substring operation does not accept a String as a character index. Expected an Integer at ...
```

What's my fault?

Comment: So your syntax and logic looks completely fine (except that `each` fits the use case better than `map`, but both work fine for this debugging). The error message implies that `filesystemsarray[0]` or `filesystemsarray[0]['partitions']` is returning a string instead of a hash, even though your debug output shows them both as a hash and facter also stores them as a hash. What values are returned from those if you access them?

Comment: the map is for the real scenario. There i have to transform some data from the nested hash into a new array.

Comment: i suspect that the fact returns a json structure which is interpreted and assigned as string. This would explain the behavior. But is in that case a way to transform the data inside yaml to real yaml format.

Comment: The fact is returning a hash. There is no json being returned for facts unless you use the CLI with the `-j` argument. If json was being returned then your `lookup` would fail. Check on the questions I asked and you will be on your way to solving the problem instead of taking shots in the dark.

Comment: No shots in the dark just some thoughts at the evening. I will try next week a work.

Comment: Ok, the above syntax doesn't change anything. I can't access the values. But I think over the problem and I solve it by using hieradata itselfs and the alias lookup function to place a hash from hieradata anywhere inside another data structure in hiera.

Comment: So my theory is correct and there is an issue with lookups farther up the keys. Good deal.